# What is the proper way to add plugins to Java EE application?

Tags: java, linux, web, tomcat

I'm trying to add the SAP connector to Java Web Application and I'm using Eclipse and Maven to build the project.

I added sapjco3.dll at C:/Windows/System32 on my local machine and libsapjco3.so at /usr/lib64/ on  AWS server (Amazon Linux 2) respectively. Then I added the sapjco3.jar file on pom.xml file like below to add the plugin and I have no problem building & running the app on my local machine and AWS server.

[pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpP5F.png)

Problem happens when I replace the WAR file on AWS server and below message pops up:

[tomcat log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSeEK.png)

It works fine if I reboot the tomcat server but I want to update the WAR file without reboot.

Based on the error message, I see that Tomcat server is trying to load libsapjco3.so again and causing the problem, which I don't know why java can't handle this. I guess either I need to add some logic somewhere to prevent loading libsapjco3.so twice or I just had set this up wrong and there is a proper way of doing this.

How can I fix this?

Amazon Linux 2
Tomcat 8.5.73
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_312-b07)

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Comment: Did you try adding the JAR file to Tomcat's common classloader (`$CATALINA_BASE/lib`) instead of the web application?

Comment: Yes, I tried adding JAR file to lib folder but didn't help.

Comment: Did you remove the JAR from your web application first?